# Tapping on maps coordinates in Appium android

Tags: android, maps, appium

I'm automating an UI testing with Appium for android and I need to test some user inputs through a map. The map is a normal google map view, integrated in my app, and I need to press for 1 second on at least 3 points in that map.
My problem, now, is that my code skip this part and goes to the next lines without errors.
Here's my code

```
    WebElement punto1=driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.RelativeLayout"));
    TouchAction touchAction=new TouchAction((MobileDriver) driver);
    touchAction.longPress(punto1, 309, 910, 3).perform();


    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement punto2=driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.RelativeLayout"));
    TouchAction touchAction2=new TouchAction((MobileDriver) driver);
    touchAction2.longPress(punto2, 320, 890, 3).perform();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement punto3=driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.RelativeLayout"));
    TouchAction touchAction3=new TouchAction((MobileDriver) driver);
    touchAction3.longPress(punto3, 299, 880, 3).perform();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I'm using the longPress(element, x,y, int duration time) and then I'm getting it pressed.
I tried to set the touch input in my area, as you can see, but I get the same problem

How can I solve this?
Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

TouchAction - Duration is in ms, so provide 1000 for 1sec. If you need 3s then duration will be 3000.

e.g. from your code: `touchAction.longPress(punto1, 309, 910, 1000).perform();`

Comment: it doesn't tap, I know it's right but my map isn't pressed (I should see a pin after 2-3 seconds of pressed tap). My code doesn't even sends an error. What can it be?

Comment: Could you try  **release()** ? touchAction.longPress(punto1, 309, 910, 3).release().perform();